# Database structure for event handling?

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, database-design

I have an event database where you can create single events or choose multi-event. Currently a `project` is created and child `event(s)` are created no matter if you choose multi-event or single event. You can then assign members to the events and choose if a project can have different members per event or all the same members for all project events. If you choose `style(project)` a member's status would be the same for all events, but if you choose `style(event)` a member could have different statuses per event. If that makes sense :)

My current structure:

```
Projects
id | multi_event(boolean) | style(project|event) | title

Events
id | project_id | title | date

Members
id | event_id | user_id | status

Users
id | name
```

My questions are as follow:

1. Should I only create a project record if you choose `multi_event(1)` or is it a good idea to keep it consistent with project records even for single events, especially since you later can change from single to multi-event?
2. Should I keep project members and event members separate depending on if you choose `style(project)` or `style(event)` with some kind of morph? Currently, if you select `multi_event(1)` and `style(project)` you'd still have to add a member to all events of the project and update the `status` field to the same value for all events of the project.

Adding a member to all events in `style(project)` seems a little redundant and as pointed out you have to update all the member's rows for `status`, but on the other hand it keeps everything consistent and I don't have to deal with members sometimes relating to `projects` and sometimes to `events`, but maybe this is what `morph` is for? Please let me know since I've never used a `morph` table in my whole life.

Hard to describe, but please let me know if you have any questions :)

Comment: serve the multi_event any purpose?

Comment: On the front end it’s showing the project title field and radio buttons for style.

Comment: To explain that further. The multi_event boolean is linked to a toggle on the frontend where you decide if it should be possible to add more than one event to a project or not as well as display a project title field if you decide that you should be able to add more than one event to a project, so I think I need the field yes. It’s not just a counter if there are multiple events.

Answer (score 0):

Redundancy is frowned on in a schema.  The column `multi_event` is arguably redundant -- the existence of more than one `event` with a given `project_id` indicates "multi-event".  (Without knowing the use of `multi_event`, I cannot say whether it is really worth having the redundancy.)

Assuming a "user" can be associated with multiple "events", `member` is a many-to-many mapping table.  Such does not need its own `id`.

Comment: I use `multi_event` to display things differently on the front end (show/hide project title etc) as well as tell it to sort the project based on the last event date of the project. I guess I could replace that by a query that checks if more than one event exists, but that seems like a lot of queries to do every time instead of just looking at a single column that tells you what to do. If this is wrong I'm happy to reconsider.

Comment: Member is a pivot table so id can probably be removed yes. I kinda like it for livewire id's and such but I can concatenate event_id and user_id for that or maybe use loop index. My main question is still about how to handle members depending on if they belong to the whole project or if they belong to individual events. Please let me know if I should try to explain that further. Thank you! Appreciate the help!

Comment: @SeaBass - You could join all 4 tables together to specify what event(s) and user(s) are involved in one project.

Comment: Thanks! So just one relation table and add project_id but no event_id if it belongs to all events of the project? Or still have one row per member and event? It’s a little redundant, but not too bad I guess. The bigger problem is member status which would have to change to the same value in all member event rows, which seems like a red flag.

Comment: What do you think? Thanks!

Comment: The best thing now is to try it.  Create the tables and the `SELECTs`.  See if the results are as expected.  (There are different ways to specify your schema and write the queries; I have nudged you in a good direction; now you need to verify that it is "good enough".)